# Complex routing WSO2 API resourse uri template

Tags: url-rewriting, wso2, url-routing, uritemplate, wso2-esb

Short Version.
I am trying to create a API that will handle

```
/goals/risks
/goals/types
/goals/{goalID}
```

So far this is what I have but it isn't quite what I am looking for. as it gives me /goals/goal/{goalId}

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="GoalAPI" context="/goals">
  <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/risks" faultSequence="ReturnError">...</resource>
  <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/types" faultSequence="ReturnError">...</resource>
  <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/goal/{goalId}" faultSequence="ReturnError">...</resource>
</api>
```

GoalID will always match `/^\d+$/` so if I can route by that somehow it will work. eventually I will want to add `/goals/{goalID}/item and /goals/{goalID}/items/{itemID}` also but I believe that will be easy enough once I figure out the first step.

If there is no way to do this here, is there a way I can rewrite the url inside wso2 before it reaches the resource and I would be able to then replace `/goals/(\d+.*)` with `/goals/goal/$1?` I know I could route it though a proxy and rewrite it in apache or something but that seems to defeat WSO2's purpose to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking into this more without success and getting no response on I just stared at the code can came up with...

```
 <api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="GoalAPI" context="/goals">
   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{goalID}" faultSequence="ReturnError">
      <inSequence>
        <switch source="get-property('uri.var.goalId')">
          <case regex="risks">...</case>
          <case regex="types">...</case>
          <default>...Handle the ID here...</default>
        </switch>
      </inSequence>
      ...
   </resource>
 </api>
```